# using google protobuffers reflection in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

How can I programatically set a field value by its name for a google protobuffer object in python. I've checked the documentation and API, but its just not clear to me, and I haven't been able to find any examples.

I'd like to do do something like:

```
protoBufObj.set_field('foo', 42)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you've got any Python object where `x.foo = 42` works, `setattr(x, 'foo', 42)` should have precisely the same effect.

Comment: @ThomasK That worked. Too bad I can't accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Have an answer to say the same thing ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've got any Python object where `x.foo = 42` works, `setattr(x, 'foo', 42)` should have precisely the same effect. This is a built-in Python function, nothing to do with protobuffers.

Comment: Will this fail if you try to set a field the proto doesn't have?

Comment: I've got `>       setattr(proto, f"debited_{self._get_proto_instance_sufix(debited_proto)}", debited_proto)
E       AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to field "debited_company" in protocol message object.` trying to do this.