# Protobuf modify field by index in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

```
proto2

message Test {
  optional string fieldA = 1;
  optional string fieldB = 2;
}
```

In Python2 how can I modify the field if I only have the index?

E.g. I'd like to set field with index 1 to "Value1"

In C++ the equivalent would be to use:

```
const FieldDescriptor *Descriptor::field(int index) const
```

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.descriptor#Descriptor.field.details

Answer (score 6):

Every generated protobuf message class has a DESCRIPTOR field: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

Take a look at [Descriptor](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/descriptor.html) documentation:

> fields: (list of FieldDescriptors) Field descriptors for all
>   fields in this type.

Therefore, to get field name by index, use:

```
field_name = message.DESCRIPTOR.fields[index].name
```

Then, you can set the value using setattr:

```
setattr(message, field_name, 'new_value')
```

(See: [using google protobuffers reflection in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456399/using-google-protobuffers-reflection-in-python))